# Exponential Generating Function of the numbers $r(n)$

Tags: combinatorics

We define $R(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}$, the exponential generating function of the numbers $r(n)$.  LEt us multiply both sides of equation by $\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Then, sum over all positive integers $n$, to get:

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n+2)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n+1)\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)r(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Now note that left hand-side is $R''(x)$, and the first member of the righ-hand side is $R'(x)$.  Te second member of the right-hand side is somewhat harder ro recognize, but ith a little practice, one can see that it is in fact $(x\ R(x))'$.

$$\therefore R''(x)=R'(x)+(xR(x))'=R'(x)+xR'(x)+R(x)$$

By solving this, we will get $R(x)=e^\frac{x+x^2}{2}$

Hey folks, I don't really get this, how do we solve "this"?

Comment: Please indicate (explicitly or by formatting) that everything except the last line is a quote; as it stands it's rather confusing before one gets to the last line.

Comment: Agreed: you haven't even copied the equation that one multiplies by $x^n/n!$ and sums over $n$.

Comment: Please don't completely change the question. Ask a new question or put a bounty on the [question you copied](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/354681). If you wish to put your bounty on that question, I can undo this bounty.

Comment: Can I put the bounty on the question I copied from?

Comment: Robjohn said that you can. Just flag a moderator explaining your request (click the *flag* text under your post)

Comment: @computer.nerd: yes, I can refund the bounty on this question. Do you want me to?

Comment: Please do so thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove by induction on $k$ the more general identity:
$$
\Delta^k h_n=\sum^k_{j=0}(-1)^{k-j}{k\choose j}h_{n+j}
$$
using $\Delta^k h_n=\Delta^{k-1} h_{n+1}-\Delta^{k-1} h_n$.

Comment: Can you do the whole question?  That way I can give you the 200 rep

Comment: You changed completely the question! I can write an answer for $\Delta^k h_0$ if you are still interested.

Answer (score 3):

"This" is a second-order differential equation, namely $R''(x) = (x+1)R'(x) + R(x)$. It has a two-parameter family of solutions, exactly one of which will have its value and first derivative at $x=0$ equal to $r(0)$ and $r(1)$, respectively. Solving differential equations is a complicated but well-studied field, too hard to summarize here.

Comment: (+1) Note moreover that the "solution" $e^{\frac{x+x^2}2}$ quoted by the OP without any reference (though beeing asked to), nor initial values, is anyway wrong. [A related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740692) gives the solution for $r(0)=r(1)=1:$ $R(x)=e^{x+\frac{x^2}2}.$