# Proving that a formula is true for $k$-th order differences of a sequence

Tags: combinatorics

How do I use induction to prove that:

$$\Delta^k h_0=\sum^k_{j=0}(-1)^{k-j}{k\choose j}h_j$$

holds for the $k$-order differences of a sequence $\{h_n\}_{n\leq 0}$

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is $k$-order differences of a sequence (of reals?) $\{h_n\}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove by induction on $k$ the more general identity:
$$
\Delta^k h_n=\sum^k_{j=0}(-1)^{k-j}{k\choose j}h_{n+j}
$$
using $\Delta^k h_n=\Delta^{k-1} h_{n+1}-\Delta^{k-1} h_n$.