# About the exponential generating function of the involutions of $\mathbb{S}_n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, involutions

I'm trying to construct the exponential generating function of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$, with $a_n$ the amount of involutions  in $\mathbb{S}_n$. So far I've made a combinatorial argument to determine the known recurrence

$$
a_n = a_{n-1} + (n-1)a_{n-2} \ \ \ (n>2)
$$

by separating in cases whether an involution $\sigma\in\mathbb{S}_n$ fixes $n$ or not. We also have $a_0 = a_1 = 1$. Now, if $f = \sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{a_n}{n!}X^n$ is the exponential generating function for this sequence, we have

$$
f = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{a_n}{n!}X^n = 1 + X + \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{a_n}{n!}X^n = 1 + X + \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{a_{n-1} + (n-1)a_{n-2}}{n!}X^n = \\
= 1 + X + \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{a_{n-1}}{n!}X^n +\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{(n-1)a_{n-2}}{n!}X^n = \\ = 1 + \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_{n-1}}{n!}X^n +\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{(n-1)a_{n-2}}{n!}X^n 
$$

Differentiating at both sides,

$$
f' = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{na_{n-1}}{n!}X^{n-1} +\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{n(n-1)a_{n-2}}{n!}X^{n-1} = \\
= \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}X^{n-1} +\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{a_{n-2}}{(n-2)!}X^{n-1} = \\
= \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{a_{n}}{n!}X^{n} +\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{a_{n}}{n!}X^{n+1} = f(1+X)
$$

This leaves us with the following differential equation,

$$
f' = f(1+X), \ f(0) = 1
$$

with solution $f = e^{X + \frac{X^2}{2}}$. Now,

$$
f = e^Xe^{\frac{X^2}{2}} = \sum_{j\geq0}\frac{1}{j!}X^j \cdot \sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{2^kk!}X^{2k}.
$$

How can I take it from here to the final 'closed' form of the exponential generating function?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You already know the e.g.f. Please look at [OEIS sequence A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085) which may have the information you are looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for the explicit calculation that starts at the expression of the egf and ends with the closed formula. I'm aware of the result, but I want to make the whole construction. So far I've described the egf in such a way that the coefficients of each monomial are not evident.

Comment: In general, if $S\subset \Bbb N$ then the generating function for the number of permutations with cycle lengths in $S$ is $\prod_{s\in S}\exp(X^s/s)$.

Comment: Okay. The expression for the egf is $\;e^{X+X^2/2.\;$ What is the "closed formula" you want to end with? Is it the  a(n) = Sum_{k=0..[ n/2 ]} n!/((n-2*k)!*2^k*k!) given in OEIS A000085?

Comment: @Somos precisely, I would like to end up getting the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{k=0}^{[ n/2 ]} \frac{n!}{((n-2k)!2^k \cdot k!)} \cdot X^n$, by manipulating the expression I have for $f$

Comment: As an observation note that involutions are given by $\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{SET}(\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})+ \textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z}))$ which yields $\exp(z+z^2/2)$ by inspection.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel would you mind explaining the notation here? I'm barely starting to study combinatorics, my knowledge of generating functions (and counting in general) is still quite rudimentary.

Comment: This is the notation from *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet and Sedgewick which is documented at [Wikipedia on AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_method_%28combinatorics%29) and [Wikipedia on random permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Many thanks for your input! I'll check out this articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the product $\;\sum_{j\ge0}\frac{1}{j!}X^j \cdot \sum_{k\ge0}\frac{1}{2^kk!}X^{2k}\;$ multiply out and get $\;\sum_{j,k\ge0}\frac1{j!}\frac1{2^kk!}X^{j+2k}\;$ and let $\;n\!=\!j\!+\!2k\;$ and thus $\;j\!=\!n\!-\!2k.\;$ Now rewrite with $\;n,k\;$  to get $\;\sum_{n\ge0}\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\frac{n!}{(n-2k)!2^kk!}\Big)X^n.$

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Sorry if I wasn't too clear when asking.