# Generating Function for the number of $n$-permutations whose square is the identity permutation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, permutations, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am learning the concept of generating functions and am working on the following problem:

> Let $r(n)$ be the number of $n$-permutations whose square is the identity permutation. We proved that
> $$r(n+2)=r(n+1)+(n+1)r(n)$$
> if $n\geq 0$, while $r(0)=r(1)=1$. Use this recurrence relation to find an explicit formula for the generating function $R(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} r(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

I have two questions:

1. How do we know when to use an exponential generating function vs. when to use an ordinary generating function? I'm guessing it has something to do with $n\cdot r(n)$ vs. $c\cdot r(n)$ where $c$ is some constant.
2. I followed the usual routine of multiplying both sides of the recurrence relation by $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and summing over all $n\geq 0$ to get
   $$\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n+2)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n+1)\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)r(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
   which can be written as
   $$\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n+2)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n+1)\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n\geq 0}nr(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
   Notice that
   $$R'(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} r(n)\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0} r(n+1)\frac{(n+1)x^{n}}{(n+1)!}=\sum_{n\geq 0} r(n+1)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
   and
   $$R''(x)=\sum_{n\geq 2} r(n)\frac{n(n-1)x^{n-2}}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0} r(n+2)\frac{(n+2)(n+1)x^{n}}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n\geq 0} r(n+2)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
   and
   $$xR'(x)=x\sum_{n\geq 1} r(n)\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0} r(n)\frac{nx^{n}}{n!}$$
   Hence,
   $$R''(x)=R'(x)+xR'(x)+R(x)$$
   $$R''(x)-(1+x)R'(x)-R(x)=0$$
   This differential equation can be solved using the power series method. Indeed, suppose $R(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kx^k$. Substitution into the differential equation gives,
   $$\sum_{k\geq 2}a_kk(k-1)x^{k-2}-(1+x)\sum_{k\geq 1}a_kkx^{k-1}-\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kx^k=0$$
   which can be simplified to
   $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\left[a_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)-a_{k+1}(k+1)-a_kk-a_k\right] x^k=0$$
   Hence we must have
   $$a_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)-a_{k+1}(k+1)-a_kk-a_k=0$$
   for $k\geq 0$. In other words,
   $$a_{k+2}=\frac{a_{k+1}(k+1)+a_k(k+1)}{(k+2)(k+1)}$$
   for $k\geq 0$.

Now I computed (I think $a_0=a_1=1$ because $r(0)=r(1)=1$)
$$k=0 \to a_2=1$$
$$k=1 \to a_3=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$k=2 \to a_4=\frac{5}{12}$$
$$k=3 \to a_5=\frac{13}{60}$$
which are exactly the coefficients of the series expansion of $e^{x+\frac{x^2}{2}}$. How can I show this? I was thinking to compute some values of $k$ (as I did above) and attempt to recognize a pattern. However, I am stuck on this part. Can I get some guidance?

Comment: Does this address your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740692/about-the-exponential-generating-function-of-the-involutions-of-mathbbs-n (An involution is an element which is its own inverse, i.e., squares to the identity.)

Comment: Also, your expression for the derivatives should have $nx^{n-1}$ not $(n-1)x^{n-1}$. That makes identifying those two series much simpler.

Comment: @semiclassical Thank you! I messed up my derivatives, everything works out now!

Comment: @Semiclassical we have an expression for the LHS and the first term on the RHS, however, I am still stuck on finding an expression in terms of $R(x)$ for the second term on the RHS $\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)r(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Comment: In general, if the problem naturally can be cast as decomposing a set of $n$ elements via a partition, and then counting something over each element of the partition, then an exponential generating function is likely to be the natural one to use.  In this case, the cycle decomposition of the permutation gives exactly such a partition, and then on each part, you put either a fixed point or a two-cycle.  So, from the general theory of exponential generating functions, I would expect the answer to be $\exp(x + \frac{x^2}{2})$.

Comment: Try splitting the second term as $n+1=(n)+(1)$...

Comment: Thanks to you guys I have made a lot more progress on the problem. I have cleaned up my post and am stuck on showing my that $R(x)=e^{x+\frac{x^2}{2}}$. Please have another look at my post, and let me know if you guys have any suggestions!

Comment: One way to proceed is to simply check that $R(x)=e^{x+x^2/2}$ solves the differential equation. But presumably you want a way to deduce this rather than confirm it. It's a linear homogeneous second-order DE, so one route (albeit tedious) will be Sturm-Liouville theory.